# Multiple Laravel applications on multiple subdomains treated as same app by Laravel cache?

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I've created 2 applications, deployed them to my server, created Apache VirtualHosts for them and I encountered really strange problem. Lets say that applications are hosted on sub1.maindomain.com and sub2.maindomain.com. When I restart Apache and go to sub1.maindomain.com everything works fine but after that when I visit sub2.maindomain.com I'm getting html from the previous application. If I restart the server once again and visit sub2.maindomain.com first i have exactly the same problem with the first application. I've tried migrating to Nginx from Apache hoping that I've messed up some configuration but nothing changed. It looks like some problem with Laravel caching, everything else works fine, problem only occurs when I have two (or more) Laravel applications as subdomains, I also have other subdomain which is just raw html and it works just fine.

This is my virtual host configuration for sub1.maindomain.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub1.maindomain.com
    ServerAlias www.sub1.maindomain.com 
    ServerAdmin www@sub1.maindomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1.maindomain.com/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/sub1.maindomain.com/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride ALL
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Configuration for sub2.maindomain.com is analogical. 
I've created both applications using `laravel new {name}` command, just like they recommend in documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
apt-get remove php5-xcache
```